# How to access selenoid ui using selenoid?

Tags: python, windows, docker, selenoid

Actually, I am trying to create new google profile in selenoid session and one of the ways that I found out is to use vnc to click some buttons that selenium can`t.

But when I am trying to get `localhost:8080` the page doesn`t load.

So, what should I do?

Comment: Selenoid UI is a separate application that should be installed. An example CM command is: `./cm selenoid-ui start`.

Comment: @vania-pooh, I have no problem starting selenoid-ui, I need to get on http://localhost:8080 in selenoid session, so I can use VNC to do some manupulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to link the selenoid and selenoid-ui containers.

```
$ docker run -d         \
    --name selenoid-ui  \
    --link selenoid     \ 
    -p 8080:8080        \
    aerokube/selenoid-ui --selenoid-uri=http://selenoid:4444
```

You have to download a browser image.

```
docker pull selenoid/firefox:88.0
```

Also, please make sure the browsers.json file is updated.

```
{
    "firefox": {
        "default": "57.0",
        "versions": {
            "57.0": {
                "image": "selenoid/firefox:88.0",
                "port": "4444",
                "path": "/wd/hub"
            }
        }
    }
}
```